# Can OpenTSB be installed on windows?

Tags: time-series, opentsdb

I'm interested in using OpenTSDB.  The first thing I observe when reviewing dependencies at:

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html#runtime-requirements

To actually run OpenTSDB, you'll need to meet the following:

•A Linux system

•Java Runtime Environment 1.6 or later

•HBase 0.92 or later

•GnuPlot 4.2 or later

Is it possible to run OpenTSDB on Windows?  I want to be able to offer users of my application the ability to run on either Linux or Windows (hence developing primarily using Java, Apache, etc.).

What are the options for a TS db that run on both OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenTSDB has worked on Windows, but you might not be able to get it to run out of the box. To build it and get dependencies you'll have to emulate autotools and wget or its equivalent to do the job. The build scripts assume a thing or two about a Linux filesystem. You'll need a Windows version of GNUPlot. Something else might come up, but nothing you shouldn't be able to overcome. And of course, you'll get HBase to run on Windows without much difficulty.